# Showing up SignalR Notification across the Pages

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I have been trying to show a notification across the page using SignalR.

**This is my startup.cs**

```
 public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var redisScaleoutConfiguration = new RedisScaleoutConfiguration(Redis.EndPoints, "SignalRKey");
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(redisScaleoutConfiguration);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
```

**And my Hub Class**

```
 public class NotificationsHub : Hub
{
    public void ContactFormSubmitted(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.notifyUsers(message);
    }

}
```

**The HTML Part**

```html
 <div class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
 
        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>Contact</legend>
 
        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="txtName">Name</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="txtName" name="txtName" type="text" class="input-medium">
 
            </div>
        </div>
 
        <!-- Textarea -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="txtComments">Comments</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea id="txtComments" name="txtComments"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
 
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="btnSubmit"></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <button id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
 
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**And Javascript**

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $(function () {
                var contact = $.connection.notificationsHub;

                // Callbacks to the client should be defined here.
                contact.client.notifyUsers = function (message) {
                    toastr.info("" + message);
                };

                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    // Calls to server should be included within the hub.start() method.
                    $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
                        // Call the ContactFormSubmitted method on the hub.
                        contact.server.contactFormSubmitted($('#txtName').val(), $('#txtComments').val());
                        // Clear text boxes and reset focus for next comment.
                        $('#txtName').val('');
                        $('#txtComments').val('');
                        return false;  // prevent 'form' from submitting.
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The Above code works to push notification.But i want the notification to be shown across the pages and not just on the page with the form.Here is the Scenario.We have a Centralized Database and all Clients are connected to the Database through a same static IP.Each of the Clients have their own Unique Office ID.We have 16 Offices each having their own office ID.Every Day we update new features with new build.Instead of sending chat message to individual client about the new changes/updates/features,we need to send it as a broadcast message like from all the offices i have mentioned there is a corporate office with OfficeId=14.So the moment the User from other office Logs in, he/she should see a pop-up notification message about the changes.I have made the form and it does shows notification but only in that particular page and not across the pages.I want to show the notification to all the users irrespective of their current page and not just the page where i have the form to send the message.

Thanks

Comment: So that has to be shown at root element or body then

Comment: Hello Sir,Once the admin submits the form,it has to be shown across the clients page.the form is now at localhost://testpage.aspx and it pops the notification only on this page..what i want is if the user is say on localhost://testpage2.aspx the notification has to be shown.

Comment: Have you used Master Page??

Comment: I have two masterpages for the project.This testpage is inheriting blank masterpage